# jquery remove not working on the responseText

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code fetches the html page and tries to remove the element.

```
$.get(url, function(responseText) {

    var e = $.parseHTML(responseText);
    e = $(e).remove("#qrform");
     ...
}
```

The removing of the element with **id=qrform** is not working. How to remove the element ?

Comment: can you try `$("#qrform").remove();`

Comment: but the complete responeseText is present in the **e** variable.

Comment: if you thin there is an item with `qrform` id, then you can just use `$("#qrform").remove();`

Comment: but the item resides in inside variable **e**. Doing anything without **e** does not make any sense . Am i missing anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not how remove works. You need to select the element

```
$(selector).remove();
```

Depending on the mark up, your code would be

```
$(e).filter("#qrform").remove();
```

or

```
$(e).find("#qrform").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search for it first then remove it

```
$.get(url, function(responseText) {

    var e = $.parseHTML(responseText);
    e = $(e).find("#qrform").remove();
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```
$.get(url, function(responseText) {
   var e = $.parseHTML(responseText);
   $(e).find("#qrform").remove();
   ...
}
```